# Ancient Message Scroll Animation idea

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I'm looking for some animation ideas to open and close this ancient scroll..
[image]

Anybody has any idea about it??

Comment: good candidate for move to http://ui.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0):

I've never done iPhone animation, but I've done just this in Flash. I'm assuming that the method would be pretty similar.

Cut out the rolled section of the scroll and place on a layer above the unrolled section of the scroll. Mask out the unrolled section of the scroll so you can't see it. Place the two rolled sections next to each other and then as you move them apart, unmask the unrolled portion such that it unmasks at the same rate the scrolled section is moving.

Comment: I haven't used flash...but yes, your logic is applicable in iphone... :)

i'll try and let u knw.. :)

Comment: i need to knw how to reveal the scroll when the right side part is moved..???

I've used setAlpha property of image view and it displays the whole scroll area before the opening animation.. any body has any idea??

i think bounds property shud be used but i dunno how to use it... :(

Answer (score 0):

How about a animated hand, grabbing the scroll, and using drag to open and close.

Or an animated wand, that taps the scroll, indents the parchment, and hey presto it opens or closes.

Comment: m not in a modd to shoot harry potter.. :| no wands or hands...i want simple scroll slide up and down...